# OSB email - forcing multipart/mixed

Tags: email, content-type, mime, osb

I am sending email using a OSB (11.1.1.6) service.

Some email clients do not pick up the attachments.

We have narrowed down the problem down to MIME Content-Type.

Going through OSB it sets the Content-Type to `multipart/related`. In order to get it to work (we tested this using ncat) we need to set the Content-Type to `multipart/mixed`.

I cannot however find any way to force OSB to set it to `multipart/mixed`.

This message **does not** display the attachment on some clients:

```
From: <nothing@example.com>
To: nothing@example.com
Message-ID: <xxx>
Subject: Subject 123
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary="MIME_Boundary";
  start=1389578236803081255-2926c9b7.148d69bfba8.7396
Return-Path: nothing@example.com

--MIME_Boundary
Content-ID: 1389578236803081255-2926c9b7.148d69bfba8.7396
Content-Type: text/html; charset="iso-8859-1"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

<h1>Head</h1>
<p>Paragraph <b>bold</b></p>
--MIME_Boundary
Content-Type: text/plain; name="TEST.txt"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Description: TEST.txt
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="TEST.txt"

VGVzdGluZyAxMjM=
--MIME_Boundary--
```

This message displays the attachment:

```
From: <nothing@example.com>
To: nothing@example.com
Message-ID: <xxx>
Subject: Subject 123
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="MIME_Boundary";
  start=1389578236803081255-2926c9b7.148d69bfba8.7396
Return-Path: nothing@example.com

--MIME_Boundary
Content-ID: 1389578236803081255-2926c9b7.148d69bfba8.7396
Content-Type: text/html; charset="iso-8859-1"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

<h1>Head</h1>
<p>Paragraph <b>bold</b></p>
--MIME_Boundary
Content-Type: text/plain; name="TEST.txt"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Description: TEST.txt
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="TEST.txt"

VGVzdGluZyAxMjM=
--MIME_Boundary--
```

As you can see the only difference is the Content-Type.

So how do I force OSB to set the Content-Type to `multipart/mixed` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some communication with Oracle support we were pointed to apply patch 12585136.

This was one of the bugs fixed for OSB 11.1.1.7 ([link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/docs/aiasoarelnotesps6-1866030.html#servbus))

- 12585136 - The Email transport generates multipart/related emails and not mulitpart/mixed

After we have applied and tested the patch I will update this answer with more feedback.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the Transport Header Content-Type. I assume you are using the routing to call the BS service which has email configuration. From Proxy, where you are routing, in the request actions, add Communication > Transport Headers. From the drop down, select emails >> Content-Type.

Comment: This only sets the Content-type for the body of the mail message and not for the whole message.

Comment: Read this  and let me know if it helps: https://blogs.oracle.com/christomkins/entry/sending_an_email_with_an_attac. I never faced issues sending attachments with OSB and receiving it on MS Exchange, Lotus Notes. Which email client are you using?

Comment: That is the tutorial I used when starting this component. All of the normal email clients we have access to picks up the attachments without a problem. We do however have a product that converts the email to a fax. This product is not picking up the attachment with `Content-Type: multipart/related` but works fine with `Content-Type: multipart/mixed`. The correct way to send the mail with attachment is with `Content-Type: multipart/mixed` but to this day I have not found a way to force OSB into it.